# Error: 'D:/Praful/Data Analytics/Case study/Apr_2022/202204-divvy-tripdata.csv' does not exist. >

Tags: r, csv, import

I am having difficulty importing a CSV or excel file to the R studio. I am getting an error as **Error: 'D:/Praful/Data Analytics/Case study/Apr_2022/202204-divvy-tripdata.csv' does not exist**. > But the path is correct (Copied path using shift+right click) and the file does exist in that path. If anyone can share the solution to fix this problem it would be a great help.

Comment: In RStudio, try importing the dataset by going to File Menu> Import Dataset > From text (readr). You can point out the file by clicking the "Browse" button in the dialogue box. Text includes CSV also. If you can import data using this, the code for this import will be in the RStudio console. You should copy and paste it in your R script or R Markdown file, so that you can run it again at a later point of time.

Comment: Hi Eva, Thank you for your reply. The CSV file is on my computer. I think the solution you have suggested works if I have the CSV file on the cloud. Please clarify.

Comment: It works for both, a local file as well as a remote file stored on a URL. The dialogue box clearly mentions File/URL. If you click on "Browse" button, it will open Windows Explorer, through which you can open the text/CSV file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I could not find the local folders in 'browse'. So I uploaded my CSV file to the cloud itself and then imported the file. I was able to explore this option through the file menu because of your valuable advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: You have a space in your path. Rename your folder `Case study` to `Case_study`  and try again.

Comment: Same with `Data Analytics` folder

Comment: Hi Phil. Thank you for your reply. I tried doing that but that didn't work either !!